# What does this mean in this context? なんかもう、色々とグダグダだ

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english, video-games

There is a sentence describing MC's thought, but no subject at all.

Context: MC is trying to rescue his childhood friend from an aliens princess. She ordered a robot (I assumed its shape looks like a taco-squid (?)) to restrain his friend ,but this robot did not listening to her and becoming unstable (spitting oil/ink at her and almost stepped on the princess herself)

> ロボの顔部分から窄めた口のようなノズルが突き出し、ブビュ！と排出された真っ黒に汚れたオイルがT-sanの可憐なドレスにかかりそうになる。
> ​
> Princess「ルー、またこいつわたくしに向かって墨吐いたのだー！」​
>
> Maid「がんばです、T-sama！！」​
>
> メイドが相変わらず、暴れるロボの手が届かないところからT-sanに無責任な激励をする。​
>
> Princess「ううぅ……、き、如月カタナぁ、お、おとなしくわたくしとせっくすするのだ！」​
>
> 「さもないとダゴン―０８ＴＣＯが、おまえの大切な　女にひどいことしちゃうんだぞ！​――ぎゃあ、こっちきた！　ばかーあっちいけ、たこー！」​
>
> MC「…………………………」​
>
> なんかもう、色々とグダグダだ……。​(this is the hard part I don't understand ,does MC talking about the robot or the princess? Also gudaguda?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"なんかもう" is typically used at the start or in the middle of an utterance when the speaker is baffled or overwhelmed and trying to figure out a way to put their thoughts into words.

色々と: "on many levels" or "in many ways/aspects.

In a somewhat new and informal usage, "グダグダ" describes a situation where there are a lot of disorganization and things are not getting done or simply botched. I think [実用日本語表現辞典](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%80%E3%82%B0%E3%83%80) hits the right note by including the glosses "収拾のつかない状態" and "だめだこりゃ、という状態". (While other dictionaries I checked gives only long-established definitions along the lines of "lazy" and "lethargic".)

The sentence has no subject, but it is clear that the speaker is talking about the unexpected and chaotic turn of events unfolding right before them.

Comment: So MC is saying "What can I say, this situation is messed up on a hole new level ...." ? something like that ?

Comment: Yup. Something like that.